# An integrand of indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need to find some examples of a function $\xi \left( x\right) > 0$, where $x \in [x_{0},\infty ),x_{0}>e
 $, such that the integral $$I =\int \frac{1}{x-\frac{x}{\ln \left( x\right) }+\xi \left( x\right) }dx$$ has a (relatively simple) closed-form solution and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\xi \left( x\right) }{\frac{x}{\ln \left(
x\right) }}=0.$$
Just in case, if $\xi ( x)  \equiv 0$, then $I =\ln ( x) - \ln ( \ln (x) +1)$.
If you can offer some $\xi \left( x\right)$ with these properties, it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: [i think] If $\xi(x)=0$ your integral, after substituting $u=\ln x,$ becomes the do-able $\int \frac{u}{u-1} du.$

Comment: Nice suggestion, then $\xi (u)$ must be of a small order
than $\frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: Max-- Do you for some reason seek nonzero $\xi(x)$? If so what other properties should $\xi$ have?

Comment: @coffeemath -- I listed all the properties of $\xi (x)$. It must be positive (not simply non-zero), have a smaller order than $\frac {x} {\ln(x)}$, and result in some digestible expression of $I$.